# Use key (id) from different table? Think this is just a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm calling some information from a table doing this:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ID=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Successfully updated! ');
} 
$details = mysql_fetch_row($result);
?>
```

This sets me up to grab various fields using:

```
<?php echo $details[0]; ?>
```

Which would grab the ID (primary key)

I then have a comment script with two functions, that draws from a different table:

```
<?
require('inc_rate.php');
getComments("1");
submitComments("1","$PHP_SELF");
?>
```

Where the "1" argument is the id (primary key) of the comment table.

I would like to be able to use the key from table_name in the arguments, so the comment script will have the same id as the item it's associated with.

How can I do this?

**EDIT: SOLVED via @achusonline 's comment**

Comment: what is preventing you from using like getComments($details[0])? are these two scripts implemented as two entirely different scripts?

Comment: @achusonline I am a moron and left a semicolon after @details[0];. DOH. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

so you can grep the ID like ID :P

```
echo $row['ID'];
```